# Load HTML template with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I am struggling to find a clean solution to my problem and was wondering if anyone could offer some tips.

I have "templates.html" which contains a collection of HTML snippets which I want to load into JavaScript and use.  What is a good way to access the templates/snippets bearing in mind that templates.html is not a loaded DOM document?

I was thinking about using `document.open` to create a DOM to access but I think this has issues on certain browsers.

Comment: SMH - it's embarrassing how many people gave jQuery answers and not Javascript ones.

Comment: A lot changed since 2011, so these present days, maybe you want look:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58862506/890357

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can load the html into a hidden div and then you will have a DOM access
the easiest way to load the html to a DIV is using jquery load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Comment: Some example code is always nice. That's why I prefer peterp's answer

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate this method in my Flask app but the html file does not load. I'd really appreciate any input! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735664/when-i-try-to-include-an-html-file-in-an-html-template-with-jquery-the-html-fil

Comment: @Felipe the answer is from 2011 you you can use it or not but you don't need to downvote

Comment: @kleinohad  jQuery has been replaced by native functions, which makes the answer outdated. IMO it should no longer be the accepted answer for a question that says "load HTML template with JavaScript"

Answer (score 45):

Use jQuery and the `.load()` ( http://api.jquery.com/load/
 ) method to inject the loaded document into the DOM.

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').load('/templates.html');
});
```

Comment: This was the solution for me, just don't forget to add the callback function! because if you are going to add functionality maybe the content is not loaded yet, so better to wait for it.
$('#content').load('/templates.html', function () {
  // Things to do when the html is loaded
});

Answer (score 32):

This is a bit old but since "Load HTML template with JavaScript" nowadays should refer to the loading of a `HTMLTemplateElement` here is a more modern looking approach to loading natives templates with javascript that also works for your use case.

First of all using `<template>` is already better than loading HTML into a hidden DIV because templates are innert and don't display content. You can have the templates being rendered from the beginning and use them whenever you need.

```
<html>
<head>
  <template>My template</template>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  document.body.append(
    document.importNode(
      document.querySelector('template').content,
      true
    )
  )
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or create them dynamically.

```
const template = document.createElement('template')
// modify the template's content
template.content.append(document.createElement('div'))
// add it to the document so it is parsed and ready to be used
document.head.append(template)
```

Because we want the content of the template to be built based on some text we get from the network, we have to parse it and add it to our `template.content`.

```
const text = fetchTemplateSomehowAsText('my-template.html')
const parsedDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html')
template.content.append(parsedDocument.querySelector('#my-snippet'))
```

If `my-template.html` already comes wrapped in the `<template>` tag we can avoid the part of creating the template element manually because the DOMParser already creates the template element for us.

```
document.head.append(
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html')
    .querySelector('template')
  )
)
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/olanod/ede8befb771057bb004c4f57be591640/) is a snippet I've been using to load templates into the document dynamically that uses what I just explained.

Answer (score 10):

another way to do this is using [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html).

```
require (['text!template_name'], function(yourTemplate) {
  // do stuff in here with yourTemplate dinamically load
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrei,  Thanks for the answer, I have not really used requirejs but was aware of it, now I have a reason to tinker..  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2285-Writing-A-RequireJS-Plugin-To-Load-Remote-jQuery-Templates.htm

Comment: you can dynamically load a lot of stuff with it, it's very usefull. I use it for coffeescript code and templates.

Answer (score 7):

For simple requiring you can try:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {     
        //do something with xhr.responseText
    }   
};      
xhr.open('GET', '/template.html');
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 4):

you could load the template async using jquery ajax

```
$.get("/html/template01.html")
.done((data) => {
    console.info(data); // output the content of the html file
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to connect that template "template01.html" to a controller (defined in controller.js (Ionic/Cordova app)) without a state?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT NOTE: if you are using ES6 go the 3rd edit directly**

What about reading the files which contains your HTML templates after loading the page and load them in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` as string value under appropriate names ?

Then you can just access your template in javascript by using the name or key specified for that template on sessionStorage or localStorage depending on which you choose.

(instead of using `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` you could preserve their stockage capabilities by designing an `object` used in `global scope` that will allow you to store `templates` and serve them on demand )

This is just theoretic I haven't tried it yet but one of the advantages I can see for this method is that you will not have your template code displayed in the page source.

**Edit:**

Going practical we can achieve this like the following.

Using `fetch` instead of `jQuery` you will have something like this :

```
var fileURL = "URL of the file to load";

fetch(`${fileURL}`).then(function(response) {
        response.text().then(function(text) {
                console.log(text); // output the file content as text
                // put data in localStorage or sessionStorage here
                localStorage.setItem("my-template", text);
        })
});
```

Now if you want your code to be executed only when `localStorage["my-template"]` exists do it that way:

```
if (localStorage["my-template"]) {
        console.log("'my-template' exist");
        // here you put the code that needs "my-template"
} else {
        console.log("error: could not find 'my-template'");
}
```

Now you can access "my-template" anywhere from javascript using :

```
localStorage.getItem("my-template");
```

Note that if you want to avoid errors the generation of your custom elements that use "my-template" should be done inside:

```
if (localStorage["my-template"]) { ... }
```

<strike>Also some minors changes may be required prior to data usage probably a simple text formatting operation. As the `data-string` contained in `localStorage` appears to contains text formatting characters.</strike> When applying the text as `innerHTML` for any `element` in the page it behaves correctly despite the text formatting chars it contains.

Given the fact that you will only get the content of your file when the `response` is resolved.

You can start the processing related to that file by :

- sending an `event` that you will attach to a function for processing
- calling a `function` that will perform the processing directly

Those needs to be done or initiated inside this part of the `fetch` instruction :

```
response.text().then(function(text) { ... })
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you do not want to put your `templates` code in the page you will need to remove the `<template>` tags that encapsulate them and add the resulting code as the `innerHTML` of the `shadow DOM` on the `customElements` that require the `templates`.

Here is a short example :

```
class TestCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    
    constructor() {
        super(); // always call first !!

        // create and attach a new shadow DOM to the element
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:"open"});  
        
        // we define the apparence of our customElement by setting it's shadow DOM innerHTML property
        this.shadow.innerHTML = `<style> 
            .container {
                width:fit-content;
                color:black;
                background-color: yellow;
                border: 1px solid red;
                padding:5px;
            }
            
            span {
                padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
            }
        </style>
        
        <div class="container">
            <span>"Hi I'm a test span !"</span>
        </div>`; 

       // here you put the functionalities  
    }
    
    // here you put the callbacks
}

customElements.define("test-custom-el", TestCustomElement);
```

If you want to try this there is this [codepen](https://codepen.io/darkosphere/pen/PoQobeQ) or you can save the above code as a `.js file`. Then you can load that file into the `header` of your test page by using this:

```
<script src="FileName.js" defer></script>
```

To add one `customElement` of that class just add those tags in the `body` of your test page :

`<test-custom-el></test-custom-el>`

Now if you want to combine this with the `fetch` example of this post you will have to remove the `<template>` tags from your templates files
and set the loaded content as the value for the `innerHTML` of the `shadow DOM` for the `customElements` that will use them.

This way there's no need to add `<template>` code into your page.

**Edit 3 :**

**BEST WAY USING ES6 :** 
After some more tests I figured it out that the best way to import an `.html` file in a `.js` file using `ES6` is to include a `.js` file **instead** of a `.html` one this way it allows the use of the `import` / `export` functionalities pretty easily without having to deal with some more heavy `async` operations that are *required to retrieve an html file in a javascript ES6 file*.

**Here is a short example on how to perform that :** 
*for this example we assume that you have a "template.html" file in the same directory as a "module.js" file*.

First You need to create a "template.js" file from "template.html" in which you put the following :

```
export default `Put the content of template.html here`;
```

*You can create a little script to create those files for you.*

When you have this "template.js" file you can now `import` it in your "module.js" file by simply using this `import` statement:

```
import template from './template.js';
```

Then you can use it to assign the `template` value of your `module` in it's `constructor` this way :

```
this.template = new DOMParser().parseFromString(template, 'text/html').querySelector('template');
```

`this.template` will now contain a `<template>` `element` as described in the "template.js" file (the element is created by the `DOMParser`).

In short your "module.js" file should look like this :

```
import template from './template.js';

export default class MyModule extends HTMLElement {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:"open"});
            this.template = new DOMParser().parseFromString(template, 'text/html').querySelector('template');
            this.shadow.appendChild(this.template.content);
        }
}
```