# DOMParser appending <script> tags to <head>/<body> but not executing

Tags: javascript, domparser

I'm attempting to parse a string into a full HTML document via DOMParser and then overwrite the current page with the processed nodes. The string contains complete markup, including the `<!doctype>`, `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` nodes.

```
// parse the string into a DOMDocument element:
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

// set the parsed head/body innerHTML contents into the current page's innerHTML
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```

This works in that it successfully takes the HTML nodes that were parsed and renders them on the page; however, any `<script>` tags that exist in either the `<head>` or `<body>` nodes inside the parsed string fail to execute =[. Testing directly with the `html` tag (opposed to `head` / `body`) yields the same result.

I've also tried to use `.appendChild()` instead of `.innerHTML()` too, but no change:

```
var elementHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

// remove the existing head/body nodes from the page
while (elementHtml.firstChild) elementHtml.removeChild(elementHtml.firstChild);

// append the parsed head/body tags to the existing html tag
elementHtml.appendChild(doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);
elementHtml.appendChild(doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

Does anyone know of a way to convert a string to a full HTML page *and* have the javascript contained within it execute?

If there is an alternative to DOMParser that gives the same results (e.g. overwriting the full document), please feel free to recommend it/them =]

*Note*:
The reason I'm using this opposed to the much more simple alternative of `document.write(data)` is because I need to use this in a `postMessage()` callback in IE under SSL; `document.write()` is blocked in callback events such as post messages when accessing an SSL page in IE =[

Comment: Have you already tried jQuery? Here you have the function [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) for parsing a HTML file. After adding a script tag via ``.append()`` should also execute it...

Comment: @tampis Yeah, tried jQuery; whenever I pass in a full HTML document to `parseHTML()`, it seems to only parse the `<head>` for some reason; if you have a working example, please by all means let me see (I could have very easily messed up in testing =P)

Comment: Related question: [javascript - Why script elements created through DOMParser do not execute? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112807/why-script-elements-created-through-domparser-do-not-execute)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `DOMParser()` as described in the question will correctly set the `<head>` and `<body>` contents of the page, but more work is necessary to get any existing `<script>` tags to execute.

The basic approach here is to pull a list of all `<script>` tags in the page after the contents have been set, iterate over that list and dynamically create a *new* `<script>` tag with the contents of the existing one and then add the new one to the page.

Example:

```
// create a DOMParser to parse the HTML content
var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsedDocument = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

// set the current page's <html> contents to the newly parsed <html> content
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = parsedDocument.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;

// get a list of all <script> tags in the new page
var tmpScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
if (tmpScripts.length > 0) {
    // push all of the document's script tags into an array
    // (to prevent dom manipulation while iterating over dom nodes)
    var scripts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tmpScripts.length; i++) {
        scripts.push(tmpScripts[i]);
    }

    // iterate over all script tags and create a duplicate tags for each
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = scripts[i].innerHTML;

        // add the new node to the page
        scripts[i].parentNode.appendChild(s);

        // remove the original (non-executing) node from the page
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also use scripts[i].parentNode.replaceChild(scripts[i], s) instead, looks a bit better imo but thank you

Comment: Also how would I deal with <script src=""> tags?

Answer (score 13):

You should use:

```
const sHtml = '<script>window.alert("Hello!")</script>';
const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(sHtml)
document.body.appendChild( frag );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo for jQuery 1.8.3 ([link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cECR/7/)):

```
var html = "<html><head><script>alert(42);</" + "script></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";

$(function () {
    html = $($.parseXML(html));

    $("head").append(html.find("script"));
    $("body").append(html.find("h1"));
});
```

Thereby I used the function `$.parseXML()` which you only can use obviously, if your HTML is also valid XML. Unfortunately is the same code not working with jQuery 1.9.1 (the `<script>` tag is not found anymore): http://jsfiddle.net/6cECR/8/ Maybe its a bug (or a security fetaure...)

Comment: I need to append the *full* contents of the `<head>` and `<body>` tags; this approach doesn't work with that - it works fine if I append individual tags (like `<h1>` or `<script>`), but then again so does raw javascript (i.e. not jQuery) and individually appending 10k+ nested tags isn't efficient enough to consider this a valid approach =/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6cECR/10/ but it is buggy... I will work again on this topic later...

Comment: Sorry, but this one doesn't work for me... the dependency of an older version of jQuery is not really a good solution. Based on that alone I haven't tested to see if it actually works in the scenario I require - Internet Explorer over SSL being used in a cross-origin callback function.