# Read or parse a html file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-parsing

I want to read a html file and then convert it into JavaScript object.

```
<!DOC TYPE html>
<html>

<HEAD>
  <META HTTP-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <META content="MS HTML 6.00.2800.1400" name=GENERATOR>
</HEAD>

<body>
  <div id='element ID'> </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Used this but this is converting a string i want to convert the whole html file.

```
<script>
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString('<TH><U>NODE INFO</U></TH>', 'text/html');
  console.log(htmlDoc)
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOMParser appending <script> tags to <head>/<body> but not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945884/domparser-appending-script-tags-to-head-body-but-not-executing)

Comment: Read about Ajax, with modern browser you can sue `fetch` function get the file as text.