# Load html templates to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am saving all the HTML templates to a single file. This file contains a loads of templates (more than 50).

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-1">
    <p>Template 1</p>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="template-2">
    <p>Template 2</p>
</script>
```

I need to load the templates to js variable.

I have looked at JQuery load method but it loads the template to attach it to DOM which is not i need here.

Any JQuery or AngularJS solution will work for me.

Comment: My question is: why? I mean, it's full of templating engines out there, just why this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I agree, I think this question needs more context to be answered properly.

Comment: I don't know why you want this, but why not an AJAX call? you could set the variable on success...

Comment: @briosheje  I have to create templates in my Angular controller based on user input. So, instead of hard-coding  it in controller js file, i wanted to put it to separate html file and load the templates as per user input and then compile the templates and render it.  Correct me if my approach sounds wrong. Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Load HTML template with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451169/load-html-template-with-javascript)

Comment: "I have to create templates in my Angular controller based on user input" what does that exactly mean? To me it sounds unlikely that that is the correct solution.

Comment: @LionC I'm assuming by *create* the OP means render and that since which template needs to be rendered is dependent on the user's input/actions they don't want to load all templates on page load but rather on demand.

Comment: @Jack If that is true there is ng-if for that.

Comment: @LionC I don't really have experience with anguler, but from what I understand using `ng-if` you are still loading that data on page load. Additionally I'm imagining that for more complex html it might be easier to just render a complete template.

Comment: @Jack together together with ng-include it should not load the content preemptively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a regular ajax call using [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the elements from the response (without attaching anything to the DOM).

For example

```
 $.get("templateUrl", function (data) {
   var $doc = $(data);
   var firstTemplate= $doc.filter('#template-1').html()
   var secondTemplate e= $doc.filter('#template-2').html()
     //..Load rest of templates into variables
 });
```