# How to load HTML template file content from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a `collection` which contains an Array of `tab` Models

like

```
[
  new TabModel({ title: 'Step 1', template: 'step1.html' }),
  new TabModel({ title: 'Step 2', template: 'step2.html' }),
  new TabModel({ title: 'Step 3', template: 'step3.html' }),
  new TabModel({ title: 'Step 4', template: 'step4.html' })
]
```

in my `View` looping over the `collection` i get the title and `template` which is placed under `templates` folder.

what will be the way to get the contents of template in `View`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load HTML template with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451169/load-html-template-with-javascript)

Comment: Getting the content of the templates is irrelevant to Backbone. It's only about loading the content of a file, which has a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. If you have minimal backbone setup you can use jQuery [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to retrieve the HTML content.

If you're using RequireJS then it has a text plugin, there are webpack modules that does this as well.