# Include file In HTML by JavaScript or jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, include

I tried the following code. But it doesn't work properly. Only one file add/ include repetitively. How can I solve this?
**I want to create a custom tag "" which can INCLUDE html file!!!! –

```js
var createIncludeTag = document.createElement('include');
$(function(){
    var includeFile = $('include').attr('href');
    $("include").load(includeFile);     
});
```

```html
<include href="nav.html"></include>
<include href="main.html"></include>
<include href="footer.html"></include>
```

Comment: HTML does not have an `include` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load HTML template with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451169/load-html-template-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`<include>` is not a valid `html` element.

You can use `<link>` element with `rel` attribute set to `"import"` to load resources into `document`. At `load` event of `<link>` element you can get the content of resource using `link.import`

```
<link rel="import" href="nav.html" type="text/html">
```

```
   $(function() {
     $("body").append($("link[href='nav.html']")[0].import.body.innerHTML)
   })
```

```
   $("link[href='nav.html']").on("load", function() {
     $("body").append(this.import.body.innerHTML)
   })
```

Alternatively, you can use `.load()`

```
   $("#element").load("nav.html");
```

Comment: Thanks,
but I want more dynamic.
I want to create a custom tag "<include>" which can INCLUDE html file!!!!

Comment: @Bapy `<link>` fetches resource, for example, an `html` `document`, which you can get using `.import` property at `load` event of `<link>` element. `<include>` is not a defined `html` element.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jquery API reference of .attr() function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName)

> **Description**: Get the value of an attribute for **the first element** in the set of matched elements.

That's why you only get the first include html loaded for all three  elements.

You have to use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) function instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("include").each(function (index, value) {
                $(this).load($(this).attr("href"));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <include href="nav.html"></include>
    <include href="main.html"></include>
    <include href="footer.html"></include>
</body>

</html>
```

By the way, creating a custom <include> TAG might not be a good idea.