# How can I create a Document object from a link (string)

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any way to create a javascript document Object by calling a function?
Something like this:

```js
<script type="javascript/text">
  var myDoc = createDocument("example.html");
</script>
```

I want to be able to create and manipulate a DOM from a string, 'example.com'.

Comment: is `"example.html"` the local file?

Comment: "example.html" is in a variable within the javascript program.

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question?

Comment: Is `example.html` an `html` `document`?

Comment: Yes it is an html document.

Comment: You can use `<link>` element with `"import"` set  at `rel` attribute to get resource as a `document` within `html` `document`. See [Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824927/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-link-script-is-still-pending-or-has-it-failed/39908873#39908873), [Include file In HTML by JavaScript or jquery dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586310/include-file-in-html-by-javascript-or-jquery-dynamically/42586440?s=6|0.0545#42586440)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you need to get html through AJAX request after use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString("<html_string>", "text/html");
```

OR

```
var doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType(
    'html',
    '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN',
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'
);

var dom = document.implementation.createDocument(
    'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    'html',
    doctype
);

 // assign the body of your page, after you can use dom variable.
dom.documentElement.innerHTML = '<head></head><body></body>';
```