# How can I make a web component using an external HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, es6-modules, html-imports

I want my HTML code for my web component to be in its own file, and therefore I would import it into the JS for my web component. I know I can use the `<link>` tag to do this, but that's [obsolete](https://chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376) now. How can I make a web component while having the HTML be in its own file, similar to Angular components?

Currently, I use `fetch` to fetch it, but that requires me to convert it into a string, then attach it to the DOM, and isn't pleasant when having multiple components. It works for now but doesn't seem right.

I read, but forgot where, I can do something like this:

```js
import * as template from "my-component.html";
```

I tried it but I received this error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Is there any normal way to import an HTML file?

Comment: Some suggestions here that may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451169/load-html-template-with-javascript/44096230. The gist is using ajax to load the HTML into a hidden div. Can be done early in the page lifecycle.

Comment: Do you mean [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)?

Comment: @Rob yes. Is web-component the wrong tag?

Comment: Well, that link may answer your questions but we cannot supply that as an answer because it's a third party site and not really an answer to your question.

Comment: Oh I've read through that before. It doesn't import html elements. It puts it in the parent DOM rather than its own file.

Comment: Package your `fetch`, string conversion, and injection into a module so you can use it in a general purpose way.