# How can I reduce the codes?

Tags: javascript

I've created many divs, it doesn't look good. Do you have a suggestion to write more cleanly? For example, I created separate divs for each pie class. Is there a shorter way to do this? Or can I use separate functions and go this way again?

```js
const arrow = document.querySelector("#arrow");
const callAllPie = document.querySelector(".allPie");
const deleteSkills = document.querySelector("#exit");
eventList();

function eventList() {
  arrow.addEventListener("click", showSkills);
  deleteSkills.addEventListener("click", deleteInfos);
}

function deleteInfos() {
  while (callAllPie.firstElementChild != null) {
    callAllPie.removeChild(callAllPie.firstElementChild);
    if (callAllPie.firstElementChild == null) {
      document.querySelector("#exit").setAttribute("style", "display:none");
      arrow.addEventListener("click", showSkills);
    }
  }
}

function showSkills() {
  arrow.removeEventListener("click", showSkills);
  //DISPLAY EXIT BUTTON
  document
    .querySelector("#exit")
    .setAttribute("style", "display: inline-block");
  const pie = document.createElement("div");
  const pie1 = document.createElement("div");
  const pie2 = document.createElement("div");
  const pie3 = document.createElement("div");
  const rightDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const rightDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
  const rightDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  const rightDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
  const leftDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const leftDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
  const leftDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  const leftDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
  const percentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const percentDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
  const percentDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  const percentDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
  const numberDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const numberDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
  const numberDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  const numberDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
  const nameDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const nameDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
  const nameDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  const nameDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
  // ADD CLASSLIST
  pie.classList.add("pie1");
  rightDiv.classList.add("slice-right1");
  leftDiv.classList.add("slice-left1");
  percentDiv.classList.add("percent1");
  numberDiv.classList.add("number1");
  nameDiv.classList.add("name1");
  pie1.classList.add("pie1");
  rightDiv1.classList.add("slice-right1");
  leftDiv1.classList.add("slice-left1");
  percentDiv1.classList.add("percent1");
  numberDiv1.classList.add("number1");
  nameDiv1.classList.add("name1");
  pie2.classList.add("pie1");
  rightDiv2.classList.add("slice-right1");
  leftDiv2.classList.add("slice-left1");
  percentDiv2.classList.add("percent1");
  numberDiv2.classList.add("number1");
  nameDiv2.classList.add("name1");
  pie3.classList.add("pie1");
  rightDiv3.classList.add("slice-right1");
  leftDiv3.classList.add("slice-left1");
  percentDiv3.classList.add("percent1");
  numberDiv3.classList.add("number1");
  nameDiv3.classList.add("name1");
  //ADD INNERTEXT
  nameDiv.innerHTML = "HTML";
  numberDiv.innerHTML = "%99";
  nameDiv1.innerHTML = "CSS";
  numberDiv1.innerHTML = "%99";
  nameDiv2.innerHTML = "BOOTSTRAP";
  numberDiv2.innerHTML = "%80";
  nameDiv3.innerHTML = "JAVASCRIPT";
  numberDiv3.innerHTML = "%75";
  //APPEND0
  pie.appendChild(rightDiv);
  pie.appendChild(leftDiv);
  pie.appendChild(percentDiv);
  percentDiv.appendChild(numberDiv);
  percentDiv.appendChild(nameDiv);
  callAllPie.appendChild(pie);
  //APPEND1
  pie1.appendChild(rightDiv1);
  pie1.appendChild(leftDiv1);
  pie1.appendChild(percentDiv1);
  percentDiv1.appendChild(numberDiv1);
  percentDiv1.appendChild(nameDiv1);
  callAllPie.appendChild(pie1);
  //APPEND2
  pie2.appendChild(rightDiv2);
  pie2.appendChild(leftDiv2);
  pie2.appendChild(percentDiv2);
  percentDiv2.appendChild(numberDiv2);
  percentDiv2.appendChild(nameDiv2);
  callAllPie.appendChild(pie2);
  //APPEND3
  pie3.appendChild(rightDiv3);
  pie3.appendChild(leftDiv3);
  pie3.appendChild(percentDiv3);
  percentDiv3.appendChild(numberDiv3);
  percentDiv3.appendChild(nameDiv3);
  callAllPie.appendChild(pie3);
}
```

Comment: Why do you create everything ? Why don't you use a template and simply show it or hide it instead ?

Comment: @Vollfeiw Yes i hadn't thought of that way thank you :)

Comment: There's sometime reason to generate content using javascript, but when you can, use a template. You can also add HTML code directly for small part instead of creating with innerHTML attribute. Also, check out this question about loading HTML template using javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451169/load-html-template-with-javascript

Comment: If you could post enough of your code that we can reproduce the problem-space you're working in, that would help us offer better answers; though the question is (arguably) a little open-ended.

Comment: This question would be good for a Code Review site, less for StackOverflow. A good start would be the usage of an iteration method such as a `for-loop`. This would already cut your code down to 25% of your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have already said, you can create a template and show/hide as needed.

If however, you require them to be generated using javascript then you can reduce the number of lines by creating one function to do all the repetitive things you're doing here.

```
    function createDiv(className, innerHTML, parentDiv)
    {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add(className);

        if (innerHTML)
        {
            div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        }

        if (parentDiv)
        {
            parentDiv.appendChild(div);
        }

        return div;
    }
```

Then simply call it like:

```
const nameDiv4 = createDiv("name1", "HTML", percentDiv);
```

Which would be the equivalent of doing:

```
const nameDiv = document.createElement("div");
nameDiv.classList.add("name1");
nameDiv.innerHTML = "HTML";
percentDiv.appendChild(nameDiv);
```